# polar form of Laplace's equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that the equation $z=f(x,y)$ is expressed in the polar form $z=g(r,\theta)$ by making the substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ and $x=r\sin\theta$. If $z=f(x,y)$ satisfies Laplace's equation $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}=0$$ then show that $z=g(r,\theta)$ satisfies the equation $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=0$$ and conversely. The latter equation is called the polar form of Laplace's equation.

Using chain rule maybe give the result. But I am having trouble to use chain rule because if I think $x$ and $y$ as functions of $r$ and $\theta$ then $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ can't found directly. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}=0=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$$

The key ingredients in the right hand side are as follows 
$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial r^2}=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\cos^2\theta+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\cos\theta\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\cos\theta\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}\sin^2\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial \theta^2}=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}r^2\sin^2\theta+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}(-r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(-r\cos\theta)+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}(-r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)+\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}(r^2cos^2\theta)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(-r\sin\theta)$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\sin\theta$$
Putting these all into the right hand side and simplifying reduces to the left hand side.